# Why some files don't have .extensions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash

I've been working with Rails for three years and never really questioned why some files don't have file extensions... Gemfile, capfile, etc. I can view read/write permissions on those files and I KIND of understand, but could use some more info on that.

thanks

Comment: That what I'd do when I don't expect other program to open it, even if it is just plain text file.

Answer (score 1):

I believe because it's not necessary to have one.

A couple good answers on [this SuperUser StackExchange question/answer](https://superuser.com/questions/334901/how-does-a-file-have-no-extension)

> most Unix utilities and applications do not care and use different heuristics to figure out a file type